# Google's Service Account OAuth2 in C#.NET for URL Shortener API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I already wasted my full day for finding sample code for Google's Service Account OAuth2 in C#.NET for URL Shortener API.

I am trying to use shortener api with server to server request.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library (you can get the API key from [here](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#APIKey))

```
string longURL="http://www.google.com";

string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + apiKey;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
var response = client.UploadString(url,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { longUrl = longURL }));

var shortUrl = (string)JObject.Parse(response)["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should read proper [Google page](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started).

Some part of it:

> Every request your application sends to the Google URL Shortener API
>   needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to
>   identify your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also
>   authorizes the request) and/or using the application's API key.

**Acquiring and using an API key**

> Requests to the Google URL Shortener API for public data must be
>   accompanied by an identifier, which can be an API key or an auth
>   token.
>
> To acquire an API key, visit the APIs Console. In the Services pane,
>   activate the Google URL Shortener API; if the Terms of Service appear,
>   read and accept them.
>
> Next, go to the API Access pane. The API key is near the bottom of
>   that pane, in the section titled "Simple API Access."
>
> After you have an API key, your application can append the query
>   parameter `key=yourAPIKey` to all request URLs.
>
> The API key is safe for embedding in URLs; it doesn't need any
>   encoding.

**Shorten a long URL**

> The Google URL Shortener API allows you to shorten URLs just as you
>   would on goo.gl. For example, to shorten the URL
>   http://www.google.com/, send the following request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
Content-Type: application/json
{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Marco. I found this NOTE on the same page Note: An API key is highly recommended.

An auth token is optional for shorten requests. If you provide one, the short URL will be unique, and it will show up in the authenticated user's dashboard at goo.gl.

Comment: is that mean if i use only API key, short URLs will not be unique?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work in windows 8 with HttpClient. Here is the code, no Api key required.

```
 var serializedUrl = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { longUrl = yourlongUrl});
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var Content = new StringContent(serializedUrl, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var resp = await client.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url", Content);
        var content = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);
        var shortedUrl = jsonObject["id"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that has worked for me. This code establishes a server to server connection and acquires an authentication token. It then makes a call to shorten the URL.  The API keys are stored in app.config.

You can read more about it here: http://www.am22tech.com/google-url-shortener-api-shorten-url/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1;
using Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

public static string shortenURL(string urlToShorten, string webSiteBasePath)
        {
            string shortURL = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            /********************************************************************/
            string AuthenticationToken = string.Empty;
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(webSiteBasePath + "/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IHSGoogleURlShortenerPrivateKeyName"].ToString(),
                                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IHSGoogleURlShortenerPrivateKeySecret"].ToString(),
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            String serviceAccountEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IHSGoogleURLShortenerServiceAcEmail"].ToString();

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { UrlshortenerService.Scope.Urlshortener }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                AuthenticationToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
            }
            // Create the service.
            var service = new UrlshortenerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IHSGoogleURLShortnerAppName"].ToString(),
            });

            // Shorten URL
            Url toInsert = new Url { LongUrl = urlToShorten };

            toInsert = service.Url.Insert(toInsert).Execute();
            shortURL = toInsert.Id;
        }

        return (shortURL);
    }
```